# Which do Pos Devices support Api for .net?

Tags: .net, api, printing, verifone

I need a pos machine which has an API for .NET. I have a [Verifone vx 680](http://www.verifone.com.tr/products/mobile/vx-680.aspx) and I contacted their help desk and asked about their supporting APIs. They wrote me

> They are not. You'll need to purchase a Developer's Package, and
>   attend a training session first. Information on this process can be
>   found here:
>   http://www.verifonedevnet.com/verifone/jsp/devnet/account/dnGetCertified.jsp

So, for using that API, I have to buy some package.

What I need is some kind of a printer/pos which can print like this

[image: ordering number]

Customers will push buttons and then I will print those numbers. However, I must be able to print these numbers via computer. In other words, I must control this printer with my program and I will be able to see which numbers printed. At the close of the day, everything must be restarted (that is, counting starts from "one" on each day)

I searched zebra printers' support APIs for .NET, but I am also looking for for a cheaper one. I don't need a developed device because it will just print some numbers to order.

Comment: I went to the Verifone training. It was intensely boring.

Comment: @MattWhitfield, haha :) So I am lucky.. My customer have verifone and   said that he can buy another one. But I dont know which is better, Because I havent any expeirience about this kind of pos/printers..

Comment: If you just want a printer that you can connect to a standard Windows PC, then go with one of the EPSON TM ones. Most devices come with what are called OPOS drivers - a quick bit of searching will help you find how to interact with OPOS from .NET (it's pretty easy).

Answer (score 0):

There is no api, you need to develop your own verifone POS application to create a communication between your Verifone 680 and your .NET desktop application.